# Does this even work with v3? No Documentation

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

So I have been spending a couple hours trying to figure out how to get google calendars to work. V3 has no calendar examples, I guess I found an older git that has the simple.php example. I entered my client id, secret, redirect, and api key.

I then browse the simple.php page and it asks for authorization, redirects back and shows Calendar List which is just an array of a bunch of random stuff not related to my calendar at all.

How do I get this to show up in an actual calendar? Why isn't there any documentation on this?

I am simply trying to get google calendar to display on a webpage for the user who is logged in. Figured there would have been a lot of documentation for something like this. Is this not possible using the google api?

```
<?php
require_once '../../src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../../src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar PHP Starter Application");

// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=calendar to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
$client->setClientId('myClientId');
$client->setClientSecret('myClientSecret');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/google-api-php-client/examples/calendar/simple.php');
$client->setDeveloperKey('myApiKey');
$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $calList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();
  print "<h1>Calendar List</h1><pre>" . print_r($calList, true) . "</pre>";

  $calendar = $service->calendars->get('primary');
  echo $calendar->getSummary();


$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}
```

Which gets me

```
Calendar List
Array
(
    [kind] => calendar#calendarList
    [etag] => "uz4dSMPAwpogj1sIr_PP7Gm-AxY/Dkoq7AkW5RQPry2qgnRZSo6dywQ"
    [items] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [kind] => calendar#calendarListEntry
                [etag] => "uz4dSMPAwpogj1sIr_PP7Gm-AxY/OfDIPQtOizBQ0xUM55cH-RiMGw4"
                [id] => myEmailAddress
                [summary] => myEmailAddress
                [timeZone] => America/Los_Angeles
                [colorId] => 15
                [backgroundColor] => #9fc6e7
                [foregroundColor] => #000000
                [selected] => 1
                [accessRole] => owner
                [defaultReminders] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [method] => email
                                [minutes] => 10
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [method] => popup
                                [minutes] => 30
                            )

                    )

                [notificationSettings] => Array
                    (
                        [notifications] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => eventCreation
                                        [method] => email
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => eventChange
                                        [method] => email
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => eventCancellation
                                        [method] => email
                                    )

                                [3] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => eventResponse
                                        [method] => email
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [primary] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [kind] => calendar#calendarListEntry
                [etag] => "uz4dSMPAwpogj1sIr_PP7Gm-AxY/sjFVOlVft6ECLQqbceDo4SWExfc"
                [id] => #contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com
                [summary] => Contacts' birthdays and events
                [description] => Your contacts' birthdays and anniversaries
                [timeZone] => America/Los_Angeles
                [colorId] => 17
                [backgroundColor] => #9a9cff
                [foregroundColor] => #000000
                [selected] => 1
                [accessRole] => reader
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [kind] => calendar#calendarListEntry
                [etag] => "uz4dSMPAwpogj1sIr_PP7Gm-AxY/R5Pe_cDz8Mqz0fmwnfeci-di2wo"
                [id] => en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com
                [summary] => Holidays in United States
                [description] => Holidays in United States
                [timeZone] => America/Los_Angeles
                [colorId] => 9
                [backgroundColor] => #7bd148
                [foregroundColor] => #000000
                [selected] => 1
                [accessRole] => reader
            )

    )

)
Notice: Undefined variable: service in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyfourteen\google-api-php-client\examples\calendar\simple.php on line 33

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyfourteen\google-api-php-client\examples\calendar\simple.php on line 33

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyfourteen\google-api-php-client\examples\calendar\simple.php on line 33
```

Comment: Not sure why someone would feel the need to down vote. Do some research I'm not the only one that is looking for documentation.

Comment: here is the documentation for the google calendar api, including code samples, how tos and api reference https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar

Comment: to clarify your question, are you trying to embed a google calendar into another webpage? if so, maybe this will help https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207

Comment: Yes but that will only display a calendar I want to make it editable just like if I was viewing a calendar on google. Doesn't seem like that is possible. Also the client libraries how tos are a joke. There is no how to for the calendar in V3, it mentions to come to stack for support lol. Also a lot of the paths and other examples are outdated.

Comment: Clearly, you can't make a calendar editable without the correct permissions. You can use the calendar API to make changes to the ACL though.

Comment: Yes I understand that and is why I thought the api would be able to do this... using oauth. I was able to get some json returned but couldn't figure out how to actually get the contents of a calendar, since well there isn't much documentation on using the client libraries. And that is why I came here as it says... "For support with the library the best place to ask is via the google-api-php-client tag on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-php-client"

Comment: I disagree. Everything the API can do is well documented here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference. What JSON were you able to get returned? And with which API call? If you post some code it might help

Comment: Well have you actually used V3 with the php client? Through out my research I came across endless threads mentioning how its outdated and people couldn't figure anything out.

Comment: At the end of the day it's just a restful api. What works in python or java will work in php too. Maybe if you posted some code I can help you out

Comment: Updated OP with code, thanks for your time.

Comment: Np I'll take a look later

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you wanna do next is to list the events in this calendar.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

You can choose what do you want to do with the calendars or events in the reference and then you can find the php example on the end of each page.